# Option to lock/unlock "Keychain login" in Keychain access "greyed out" and unable to change

Tags: xcode, apple-m1

My problem is actually related to another common xcode problem;
"Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code"

However, in order to try one of the resolutions to this problem, it was recommended that I
lock/unlock the Keychain login. Any help is much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This message is a very basic error message that just states that the build did not finish successfully. To view what actually caused the build to fail, you would have to click on the right-most tab on the left panel (which also contains the tab for your folder structure). This should give you list of recent build processes. Select the one that failed (red x) to see the logs. At the very bottom, you will find your error.